# iTunes Connect - Expedite Review Process

Tags: app-store-connect

I want to submit an application for expedite review. Can someone please let me know the process for it. Do I need to submit the expedite review form before or after submission of the IPA in iTunes Connect. Is there any timeline by which review process is initiated.

Any additional information or experience associated with the expedite review process is also welcome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: epascarello - Agreed that this is nothing to do with programming but I think along with me some other developers too might have this question and they will come to stackoverflow for the answers. So I think we can keep this question for future reference too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this article.

https://mobileroadie.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200091766-Requesting-Expedited-App-Review-on-iTunes

Essentially:

1. Login to iTunes Connect using your iOS Developer Account credentials
2. Scroll to the bottom of the iTunes Connect webpage and click 'Contact Us'
3. Select 'App Review' and 'Request Expedited Review', then select 'Request an Expedited App Review'

Fairly straightforward

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, its great, But do I need to submit the expedite review process before or after submission of the IPA or it should be done after submission of the IPA and which it is still in Waiting for Review process.